# Descending by average value using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I faced a problem with entity framework. I'm trying sort my collection by average value from one of the key:

```
var userPhotos = Database.Set<Photo>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId);
usersPhotos = usersPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => item.Votes.Average());`
```

In the last line of code I have *"The specified type member 'Votes' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."* execpetion.
My member Votes looks like so:

```
public class Photo : BaseEntity, IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Photo()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Votes = new List<double>;
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //Other fields
    public ICollection<double> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

How to fix my problem and make sort by avarege value of this member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to is ToList() at the end of the first line.

You can do it this way;

```
var userPhotos = Database.Set<Photo>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId).ToList();
var sortedUsersPhotos = usersPhotos.Where(p=>p.Votes!=null && p.Votes.Any()).OrderByDescending(item => item.Votes.Average());
```

Comment: It creates a new object is not mandatory. Is it a more elegant way?

Comment: Where does `usersPhotos` come from?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: If so, I need to create a new variable for sorted photos otherwise I have types conflict.

Comment: Yes.. Didn't notice you have used the same name. Yes you have to create a new variable.

Comment: Damn it! `Average()` throw an execption for empty votes collection:(

Comment: Is it better to create one more member in database with average value and sorting by average key?

Comment: ok. Really?? Just.. have a look at the updated answer

Comment: What will happend with order if every item contains empty votes member or some of them?

Comment: What do you mean by empty votes member?

Comment: I guess you meant 0 members. Ok. Answer updated. These are very basic things that you should be able to fix by yourself.

Comment: I think it's better to write like `(p => p.Votes.Count != null)`

Comment: Oh. no.. I am going to stop it there. You need to figure it out.

Comment: I mean `(p => p.Votes.Count != 0)` It was misprint.

Comment: You've got to look more. Even `(p => p.Votes.Count != 0)` is not correct and cannot be recommended even with the correct syntax. Better approach is `Any()`

Comment: When you ask me what I mean by empty votes member, I mean that current code skip objects which have no votes. So it ordering photos only with rating. It is not what I want. I need all photos even with 0 votes.

Comment: Update your answer to `sortedPhotos = userPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => (item.Votes == null || !item.Votes.Any()) ? 0 : item.Votes.Average());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy:

```
var sorted = userPhotos.GroupBy(item => item.Votes.Average()).OrderByDescending(item => item.Key);
```

If you want to use the same object:

```
userPhotos = userPhotos.GroupBy(item => item.Votes.Average()).OrderByDescending(item => item.Key).SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Comment: Tried the second version, still "NotSupportedExecption"